# MockWebServer is making actual calls to my service instead of mocking them

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently developing a microservices app using Spring Boot. I am attempting to write a test for my user-service WebClient using MockWebServer. However, it appears that MockWebServer is sending a real request to the service instead of mocking it. This issue persists even when the service is running, likely due to my usage of Eureka discovery for service registration.

```
public class UserClientTest {
    private MockWebServer mockWebServer;
    private UserClient userClient;
    @Autowired
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        mockWebServer.start();

        webClientBuilder = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/users").toString());
        userClient = new UserClient(webClientBuilder);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        mockWebServer.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should create a new user")
    public void shouldCreateANewUser() {
        UserResponse mockResponse = new UserResponse(1L, "john_doe", "john@example.com");
        mockWebServer.enqueue(
                new MockResponse().setResponseCode(201)
                .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .setBody(new Gson().toJson(mockResponse))
        );

        // Perform the actual method call
        UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest("john_doe", "password", "john@example.com");
        Mono<UserResponse> createUserMono = userClient.createUser(userRequest);
        StepVerifier.create(createUserMono)
                .expectNext(mockResponse)
                .verifyComplete();
    }

}
```

```
@Component
public class UserClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://user-service";
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public UserClient(@Autowired WebClient.Builder webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient.baseUrl(BASE_URL).build();
    }

    public Mono<UserResponse> createUser(UserRequest userRequest) {
        return webClient.post()
                .uri("/users")
                .bodyValue(userRequest)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(UserResponse.class);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because the following `UserClient` 's constructor  always fix the `WebClient` 's base URL to `http://user-service` which override the setting you configure in the test :

```java
@Component
public class UserClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://user-service";
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public UserClient(@Autowired WebClient.Builder webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient.baseUrl(BASE_URL).build();
    }
}
```

To be more flexible , it should respect the setting of the input `WebClient.Builder` :

```java
    public UserClient(@Autowired WebClient.Builder webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient.build();
    }
```

The client can then define the base URL by themself such as :

```java
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(UserClient.BASE_URL);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working, but the problem here is what if we have more than webclient with another services ? because this configuration it will work only with one service "return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(UserClient.BASE_URL);"